# Код, который работает в Google Colab не запускается в командной строке Windows

Tags: python, telethon, google-colaboratory

Коллеги, у меня следующая проблема. Пишу парсер для поска сообщений в чатах Telegram по ключевым словам. Пишу на python в Google Colab. Написанный код в Google Colab работает исправно. Сохраняю его в файл с расширением .py и запуска через командную строку Windows. Фрагмент кода ниже:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime
import schedule
import time
import pandas as pd
import configparser
import json
import asyncio

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

api_id   = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']
username = config['Telegram']['username']
    
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
await client.start()
print(await client.get_me())
```

После запуска данного фрагмента кода командная срока выдает ошибку - syntaxerror: 'await' outside function. Ок. Заворачиваю фрагмент в асинхронную функцию.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime
import schedule
import time
import pandas as pd
import configparser
import json
import asyncio

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

async def main():
    api_id   = config['Telegram']['api_id']
    api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']
    username = config['Telegram']['username']
    
    client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()
    print(await client.get_me())
    
    client.run_until_disconnected()
asyncio.run(main())
```

После запуска кода командная строка просит ввести номер телефона и пароль. Ввожу номер телефона и пароль. После этого моя учетная запись в Telegram отваливается от смартфона и потом сутки я не могу закрыть никакие сессии, видимо срабатывает какая-то защита Telegram. Кто-то сталкивался с таким? Как этого избежать?
[image: Прилагаю скрин выдачи сообщения от командной строки после ввода логина и пароля.]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью коллеги разобрался. Строчку:

```
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
```

Нужно переписать вот так:

```
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash, system_version='4.16.30-vxCUSTOM')
```